# Prove that, there exist uncountably many multiplicative maps from $\Bbb{Q}^\ast\to\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, integers

First of all, I should define multiplicative map-
A map $f:\Bbb{Q}^\ast\to\Bbb{Z}$ is said to be multiplicative map if $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)\ \forall a,b\in \Bbb{Q}^\ast $, here $\Bbb{Q}^\ast=\Bbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$.
Let us assume on contrary, it is countable, and let the countable collection of all multiplicative maps be written by the enumeration $f_1, f_2,\ldots , f_n,\ldots$
Now, I want to construct another multiplicative map $\psi:\Bbb{Q}^\ast\to\Bbb{Z}$ using the maps $f_1, f_2,\ldots , f_n,\ldots$ but $\psi\ne f_i\ \forall i\in\Bbb{N}$. But I can't construct such a map.
Is there any other method to solve this problem? Can anybody suggest me a proper way out?
Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: Look at $f(p_n)$, where $p_1=2$, $p_2=3$, $p_3=5$, ... are the primes.

Comment: To make the above hint more explicit: rather than explicitly using the Cantor construction, try and use it _implicitly_, by finding a (sub)set of multiplicative maps isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The requirement $\operatorname{rang}f\subseteq\Bbb Z$ is odd. Note that $f(a)f(1/a)=f(1)$, so fixing $f(1)$ gives $f$ only finitely many possible ideas, despite the fact $f(a^n)=f(a)^n$.

Comment: Maybe this is the wrong idea but $f(a)=a^x$ will be such that $f(ab) = (ab)^x = a^xb^x =f(a)f(b)$ so for every $x$ there is a multiplicative map.  You just need to believe $a^x$ for irrational $x$ is definable.  Which.. it is.  So, am I missing something?

Comment: @fleablood: How is $2^{\sqrt2}$ an integer? It's not even rational.

Comment: @J.G. what do you mean by fixing $f(1)$? Don't we have $f(1) = 1$ because $f(a) = f(1a) = f(1)f(a)\ \forall a$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well I *did* ask if I was missing something :)   Apparently I was missing this was being mapped to the integers.

Comment: And if $f(1)=0$ then $f=0$.

Comment: @RGS If $f(1)=1$, $f$ can only be $\pm 1$; if $f(1)=0$, $f$ can only be $0$.

Comment: I have to find a multiplicative map $\psi\ne f_i\ \forall i$

Comment: From the first hint, I'm trying to construct $\psi:\Bbb{Q}^\ast\to\Bbb{Z}$ in such a manner, $\psi(p_i)=f_i(p_i)+1$, where $p_i$'s are prime arranged in increasing order. But where do the points of $\Bbb{Q}^\ast\backslash\{p_i:i\in\Bbb{N}\}$ map to under $\psi$? Keeping in mind new map must be multiplicative.

Comment: Assume as in the OP we can count. Let $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_r,\dots$ be the full list of all primes. Choose now values $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r\in\{\pm 1\}=\Bbb Z^\times$ such that $v_1\ne f_1(p_1)$, $v_2\ne f_2(p_2)$, ... , $v_r\ne f_r(p_r)$, ... and construct the multiplicative function $f$ which satisfies $f(p_j)=v_j$ (and $f(-1)=1$). Where is it in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(a)$ admits an inverse, or $f(a)=0$. So there are really only three options for $f(a)$, which are $-1,0,1$. Moreover, $f(1)\neq -1$.

Let $\Bbb P$ denote the set of primes $\{2,3,5,\dots\}$ and let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime, starting with $p_0=2$.

For $A\subseteq\Bbb P$, define $f_A(1)=1, f_A(-1)=-1$ and $f_A(p)=1$ if and only if $p\notin A$, and $f_A(p)=-1$ otherwise. I claim that this is enough to determine $f_A$ entirely.

- For every $k\in\Bbb N$, write $k$ into its decomposition into primes, then $f_A(k)$ is determined exactly by the values given.
- For every $k\in\Bbb{Z\setminus N}$, define $f_A(k)=-f_A(-k)$. Since $f_A(-1)=-1$, this definition is still multiplicative.
- Next for $k\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ define $f_A(\frac 1k)=f_A(k)$.
- Finally, we get $f_A(\frac nm)=f_A(n)\cdot f_A(\frac 1m)$.

Now simply prove that if $A\neq B$, then $f_A\neq f_B$. But that's easy. And observe that $\mathcal P(\Bbb P)$ is in fact uncountable.

Comment: $f_A(p)$ is not defined for $p\in A$. And setting $f_A(1/p)=0$ will not really work in the needed multiplicative relation $$f_A(1)=f_A(1/p)f_A(p)\ .$$

Comment: Dangit, you're right. But it would work if I decide $f_A(\frac1p)=-1$ instead, right?

Comment: Yes, we can and must use only $\pm 1$ for the images of a multiplicative map $(\Bbb Q^\times , \cdot)\to (\Bbb Z, \cdot)$. So a good map $f_A$, parametrized by subsets $A$ of $\Bbb P=\{2,3,5,\dots\}$ is $$f_A\left(\prod _{p\in \Bbb P} p^{a(p)}\right):=\prod_{p\in A}(-1)^{a(p)}\ .$$ And the subsets of $\Bbb P$ build an uncountable set...

Comment: @dan_fulea what do you mean by $a(p)$?

Comment: @BiswarupSaha: I am guessing that this is the multiplicity of $p$ in the prime decomposition of some integer (or rational, you care for negative exponents directly.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila in the first line you have said $f(a)$ is invertible or $0$. Is this true for all multiplicative maps? If yes, why?

Comment: Yes, each element in $\Bbb Q_{>0}$ has a unique decomposition as a product of the primes $p$, taken each to a corresponding integer power $a(p)$. All but finitely many powers are zero, of course. (Above i should maybe have written $\pm \prod_{p\in\Bbb P} p^{a(p)}$ to have a definition working for all $\Bbb Q$. So $f_A(-1)=1$.)

Comment: @BiswarupSaha: Trivially. $f(a)\cdot f(\frac 1a)=f(a\cdot\frac1a)=f(1)$. And $f(1)=f(1\cdot 1)=f(1)\cdot f(1)=f(1)^n$. So $f(1)=0$ or $f(1)=1$.